# How would I solve an equation of the following type: $ ax+b = ce^{dx^2}$

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w

I wish to solve an equation of the following type: $ ax+b = ce^{dx^2}$.
I know about Lambert W function, however I do not see any way of solving the equation with $x^2$ instead of $x$. Is this possible?

Comment: I think it is unlikely, since Mathematica cannot solve even the case $x+1=e^{x^{2}}$. Of course, Mathematica is not perfect, and I am no expert. If $b=0$, however, then you can solve it by squaring both sides, solving the resulting equation for $x^2$, and discarding extraneous solutions.

Comment: Maybe useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309691/equations-solvable-by-lambert-function